# Nodemailer without Gmail

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm using NodeJS and I want to configure my email account with [**Nodemailer**](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer).

All the **Nodemailer** examples that I found are for Gmail...

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'gmail.user@gmail.com',
        pass: 'userpass'
    }
});
```

How can I put another service? In special I bought a email domain in [**ovh**](https://www.ovh.co.uk) (**SSL0.OVH.NET**) and I interested to configure this email account.

I tried but I don't found the way to get this...

*Thank you!*

Comment: Did you try the [smtp transport](https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-smtp-transport) ?

Comment: your link helps me a lot. Now is working!!!! Thank you a lot!!

Comment: @AralRoca I know this is an old question but I am facing the same problem. Even using smtp transport (using the following host and port: https://getmailspring.com/setup/access-ovh-net-via-imap-smtp)

Answer (score 5):

I create a module `Mail` for send html mails by SMTP

```
exports.send = function(email, subject, htmlcontent, callback) {
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
    var configMail = require('../bin/config').mail;//my json configurations mail

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
        host: configMail.host, //mail.example.com (your server smtp)
        port: configMail.port, //2525 (specific port)
        secureConnection: configMail.secureConnection, //true or false
        auth: {
            user: configMail.auth.user, //user@mydomain.com
            pass: configMail.auth.pwd //password from specific user mail
        }
    }));

    var mailOptions = {
        from: configMail.email,
        to: email,
        subject: subject,
        html: htmlcontent
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info){
        transporter.close();
        if(err) {
            callback(err, info);
        }
        else {
            callback(null, info);
        }
    });
}
```

The usage:

```
var Mail = require('../utils/Mail'); //require this module
Mail.send('[EMAIL TO SEND]', '[TITLE]', '[YOUR HTML TEMPLATE MAIL]', function(err, info) {
    if(err) {
        //error
    }
    else {
        //Email has been sent and you can see all information in var info
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of Nodemailer is this code for? Current version docs define different signature https://nodemailer.com/smtp/

Comment: tested with versions package nodemailer ^1.8.0 and nodemailer-smtp-transport ^1.0.3

Answer (score 1):

On creating an email id in the domain (mostly through c panel), check the mail configurations for that mail address and look for SMTP details such as port, username, etc. Then enter those details in the nodemailer transporter. For example, my transporter details were:

```js
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "mail.schoolprogramming.tech",
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: "demo@schoolprogramming.tech",
      pass: "**************"
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand this is just an example, but I would recommend changing anything with credentials to `process.env.USER` and stuff, to help newer devs stay away from bad practices like storing login credentials in a string.